# How to set correctly routes and other configurations in Laravel framework and run code examples from books?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, bitnami

I am trying to run the code from a book "Laravel blueprints", chapter 4: "Personal blog" on Laragon and Bitnami Laravel stacks.

I put all the controllers, views, models and routes in respective app folder, set up database so it shows connection and tables migrated, however, when I want to run home page, it says: "Post class not found". I can`t return the home view of the blog. Please help: what I have missed in configurations, how to run examples from book on Laragon and Bitnami Laravel, what files to copy, what remain unchanged and what to configure?
Thanks

```
 <?php



class PostsController extends BaseController{



public function getIndex()

{

    $posts = Posts::with('Author')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);

    return View::make('index')

            ->with('posts',$posts);

}



public function getAdmin()

{

    return View::make('addpost');

}

public function postAdd()

{

    Posts::create(array(

           'title' => Input::get('title'),

           'content' => Input::get('content'),

           'author_id' =>  Auth::user()->id

       ));



       return Redirect::route('index');

}
```

}
 -

class Post extends Eloquent {

```
//the variable that sets the table name

   protected $table = 'posts';



   //the variable that sets which columns can be edited

   protected $fillable = array('title','content','author_id');




   public $timestamps = true;



   public function Author(){



    return $this->belongsTo('User','author_id');

   }
```

}

```
 <?php
```

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
 Route::get('/', array('as' => 'index', 'uses' =>
'PostsController@getIndex')); Route::get('/admin', array('as' =>
'admin_area', 'uses' => 'PostsController@getAdmin'));
Route::post('/add', array('as' => 'add_new_post', 'uses' =>
'PostsController@postAdd')); Route::post('/login', array('as' =>
'login', 'uses' => 'UsersController@postLogin'));
 Route::get('/logout', array('as' => 'logout', 'uses' =>
'UsersController@getLogout'));
```

Comment: try `composer update` on your terminal in your root folder of your laravel installation (one level above your `app` folder)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a namespacing error, I had struggle with it at the beggining too.

Please show us you Post class code, your routes.php file and the controller that is throwing the error.

Actually before doing this, change all places in script where you use Post:: for \App\Post::

Comment: Nothing helps, computer is offline, what to do?

Comment: <?php

use App\Posts; 

class PostsController extends BaseController{

Comment: You have forgotten to import all class you need, namespaces are something new in PHP so you can either make reference to Post class by using the full route (\App\Posts::) or by defining that (use App\Posts;) and then you can reference simply using Post::